# If i specify app.engine in express, do i need to app.set view engine also?

Tags: express, templates, ejs, template-engine, viewengine

I'm learning Node.js and at template topic right now. First i used only EJS and configured `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` for it to work properly. Next to create layout i installed ejs-mate and added `app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-mate'))` in my code. But what does it actually do? As i understood `app.set` is configuring my server view engine to be EJS. Thank to this setting our server would know how to parse code of our templates into pure HTML. And `res.render` would send rendered HTML to client. By `app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-mate')` am i specifying .ejs files to be rendered by ejs-mate render function? Why do i still need `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`? It seems to be working without it.

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Comment: Nope, but i moved on

Comment: Okay thx and good luck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain why you need `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`

Basic setup using [EJS](https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express).

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {foo: 'FOO'});
});

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!'));
```

---

After the view engine is `set`, you don’t have to **specify** the engine or **load** the template engine module in your app. Express loads the module internally.
If the view engine property is **not set**, you must specify the extension of the view file. Otherwise, you can omit it. I hope this explanation gives you better understanding ;-) I know from experience that it is better to stick to the **documentation**
You can read more about it [here.](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html#using-template-engines-with-express)